# if x^2 + 2x - 3 >= 0 then (x <= -3) V (x >= 1)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know why this is true but putting it in symbolic notation has me stumped. 
so basically i have that:

```
Vx E R, [(x^2 + 2x - 3 >= 0) => [(x <= -3) V (x >= 1)]
```

not sure how to go on with proving this really... I know that x^2 + 2x - 3 is greater than or equal 0 on the intervals [-infinity, -3] and [1, infinity] which means that the consequence of the statement above holds true. But how do i write that?

```
Assume x^2 + 2x - 3 >= 0
       (x+3)(x-1) >= 0
        x = -3,1
```

and that's where i draw a blank...any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Think about when a product is positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

The curve $\;y=x^2+2x-3=(x+3)(x-1)\;$ is an upperward parabola intersecting the abscisas axis at $\;x=-3\;,\;\;x=1\;$.

Just draw it and check that this parabola is non-negative precisely when $\;x\le -3\;$ or when $\;x\ge 1\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write down this proof.  For any $\;x\;$,
\begin{align}
& x^2 + 2 x - 3 \ge 0 \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"arithmetic"} \\
& (x + 3) (x - 1) \ge 0 \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"property of $\;\times\;$ and $\;\ge\;$"} \\
& (x + 3 \ge 0 \land x - 1 \ge 0) \;\lor\; (x + 3 \le 0 \land x - 1 \le 0) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify"} \\
& (x \ge -3 \land x \ge 1) \;\lor\; (x \le -3 \land x \le 1) \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"simplify"} \\
& x \ge 1 \;\lor\; x \le -3 \\
\end{align}

This also shows that your implication ($\;\Rightarrow\;$) is even an equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 + 2x -3 = (x + 3)(x-1)$.  You want this to be greater than (or equal to) zero, hence you need either both $x +3, \ x-1$ to be positive or both negative, which is where it is greater than zero.

And so, you need to solve the following inequalities:

**Both positive:** $x +3 > x -1 \ge 0$.

**Both negative:** $ 0\ge x+3 >x -1$.

Therefore, for the positive case, you have that $x \ge 1$.
And for the negative case, you have $x \le -3$. In other words, $x \in (-\infty, -3] \cup [1, \infty)$ or $(x\le -3) \vee (x \ge 1) $.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x):=x^2+2x-3=0\iff x=-3\lor x=1$ the sign of $f$ is constant on the intervals $]-\infty,-3[$, $]-3,1[$ and $]1,\infty[$.